# Diffie hellman small shared secret

Tags: diffie-hellman

Is there a way to prevent the shared secret to be a small value (eg 4) to avoid easily succeeding brute force attacks?

In $g^a \bmod p$, I understand that choosing $p$ not a multiple of $g^a$ is a first step.
But other than that, are there fast ways to achieve that goal?

Thanks

Comment: By the same reasoning, *all* possible shared secrets are insecure: What if an attacker simply guesses that $g^{ab}\bmod p$ lies in a certain "small" range and brute-forces that range?

Comment: You are perfectly right

Comment: Note that excluding a certain range of values from potential secrets will reduce the entropy of the secret and hence make brute forcing easier. Values from the excluded range of values will not have to be tested.

Comment: @JimmyB correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $p$ is a prime number and $g^a\bmod p$ will fall between $[1, p-1]$, so $p$ will never be a multiple of $g^a \bmod p$ unless $g^a= 1\bmod p$.
2. In Diffie Hellman, the secret exponents $a,b$ are chosen uniformly and randomly from $[1,q-1]$, where $q$ is a very large number. The probability that $Pr[g^{ab} = 4]$ or more generally $Pr[g^{ab} = x]$ for any $x$ in the group is negligible. This implies that for any integer $y=poly(n)$ where $n$ is the security parameter and $poly(\cdot)$ is any polynomial, $Pr[g^{ab} \le y]$ is negligible as well. So you don't need to worry about the key being a small value.

Comment: Ok thanks! Since we cannot do anything against a very lucky attacker, it will do!